# Why are two similar objects not equal

Tags: java, object, equals

I have these two object which have all equal fields.

Why does `obj1.equals(obj2)` return false?

[image]

Comment: Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Comment: Can you please read docs of equal method in Object class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't override equals method, then when you are doing

```
obj1.equals(obj2)
```

It is comparing the values as displayed in your image.

```
"com.waze.testing.data.Pin@4355".equals("com.waze.testing.data.Pin@4361")
```

which will returns `false` as per your result.

Comment: if these are two instances of the same class with only int Strings and a float - I don;t think i need to override the equals. no?

Comment: (Second one should be "@4361")

Comment: updated the answer. @USER1065869 No,you still need to override the equal instance, else it will compare the instance which is unequal in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behaviour of equals(comparing references). So, if `==` returns false on Object, `.equals()` returns false as well. Unless you have overidden `equals()`.

Comment: if these are two instances of the same class with only int Strings and a float - I don;t think i need to override the equals. no?

Comment: You do if you want it to work the way you expect it to.

Comment: 2 *instances* have 2 *separate* locations in memory. So, `==` returns false (compares references), so does `equals()`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you override `.equals()`? If not, it is using `Object.equals()` which only returns true if they are the exact same instance.

Comment: if these are two instances of the same class with only int Strings and a float - I don;t think i need to override the equals. no?

Comment: @user1065869: Yes, you do.  The default implementation of `equals()` compares the *references*.  So unless they're the same instance of the object, they're not equal.  To change that logic, you need to override the method.